# On the binomial sum $\sum_{j\in\mathbb Z} \binom nj \binom{-n}{j+l}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

For $n\in\mathbb R$ and $l\in \mathbb Z$, I am interested in the binomial sum
$$F(n,l) = \sum_{j\in\mathbb Z} \binom nj \binom{-n}{j+l}.$$
Here, the binomial coefficient $\binom nm$ is defined for $n\in\mathbb R$ and $m\in\mathbb Z$. It is zero for $m<0$, and otherwise it is defined as
$$\binom nm = \frac{n(n-1) \cdots (n-m+1)}{m!}.$$
Mathematica gives
$$F(1/2, 10) = \frac{2}{21\pi}, \quad F(1/3, 4) = \frac{3\sqrt 3}{26\pi}, \quad \mathrm{etc.}$$
Although it does not give the answer for general $n,l$, I suspect there is a closed formula. What is it?

Comment: Could you show the syntax you used for Mathematica ? It *could* be related to some hypergeometric function.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Since $c_{j + 1}/c_j$ is a rational function of $j$, the sum has to be a hypergeometric function. For $l < 0$, we can take $j' = j + l$. For $l \geq 0$,
$$\binom n j \binom {-n} {j + l} =
\binom {-n} l \frac {(-n)_j (n + l)_j} {(l + 1)_j} \frac 1 {j!},$$
so we get a ${_2 F_1}$ function. Gauss's theorem gives an elementary closed form.

Comment: @Maxim. Thank you.